Using a TextField as one of the options of MUI Autocomplete
In a React app, I'm using a MUI Autocomplete field as a searchable dropdown. I'm trying to make 1 of the options be a TextField in which the user can fill in some text.
Rendering this TextField is working fine, but I cannot get it to allow the user to select the TextField by clicking on it.
Is there a way to make it possible for the user to highlight this TextField and start typing text in it, without the Autocomplete options list closing down?
Edit after comments: When clicking the regular options, the dropdown should closeOnSelect like normal.


Or this static code below:
import "./styles.css";

import { Autocomplete, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("");
  return (
    <Autocomplete
      options={["Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3"]}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} />}
      renderOption={(props, option) => {
        if (option == "Option 3") {
          return (
            <li {...props}>
              <TextField onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()} />
            </li>
          );
        } else return <li {...props}>{option}</li>;
      }}
      value={selectedOption}
      onChange={(_, newValue) => {
        if (newValue) {
          setSelectedOption(newValue);
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}




Stop event propagation: Use onMouseDown and onClick handlers to stop the click event from propagating.
Prevent Autocomplete close: Use the disableCloseOnSelect prop to
ensure clicking the TextField doesn't close the dropdown.

Code :
import "./styles.css";
import { Autocomplete, TextField } from "@mui/material";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("");
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState(""); // TextField input value

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      options={["Option 1", "Option 2", "Custom Option"]}
      disableCloseOnSelect // Prevent closing on select
      renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Select an option" />}
      renderOption={(props, option) => {
        if (option === "Custom Option") {
          return (
            <li {...props} onMouseDown={(e) => e.stopPropagation()}>
              <TextField
                value={inputValue}
                placeholder="Type here..."
                onChange={(e) => setInputValue(e.target.value)}
                onClick={(e) => e.stopPropagation()} // Prevent list close
                fullWidth
              />
            </li>
          );
        }
        return <li {...props}>{option}</li>;
      }}
      value={selectedOption}
      onChange={(_, newValue) => {
        if (newValue) {
          setSelectedOption(newValue);
        }
      }}
    />
  );
}


Thanks, but with this implementation the Autocomplete dropdown will still close, see this sandbox with your code:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/2dwzsx
. And unfortunately I do need the autocomplete to close on selecting the non-textfield options, so I think disableCloseOnSelect will not work for what I'm trying to achieve.
